# AJAX Call not Getting to Spring MVC Controller

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring

I'm trying to make a simple AJAX call in my Spring MVC project but am running into trouble. I am making my AJAX request by sending an String type argument and I'm wanting to get an ArrayList type back. I've read many tutorials at this point and can't figure out what's wrong with my AJAX/Controller configuration. I am using the ResponseBody annotation when trying to return my needed result back to the view. In this controller I am not returning an updated ModeAndView object, but this shouldn't matter since the page does not need to be refreshed because I'm using AJAX. Below is my AJAX call and controller code. I would really appreciate it if someone could give me a hint on what I'm doing wrong here.

```
     function getdays() {
   var monthSelected = $("#monthselect option:selected").text();
   alert(monthSelected);
$.ajax({

    url : '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/ajaxdays',
    data: monthSelected,
    success : function(data)
    {
        $('#daySelect').html(data);
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

}
Here is my controller class:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes
public class WorkstationController
{

    @RequestMapping(value = "/ajaxdays", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody
    ArrayList<String> getTime(HttpServletRequest request) 
    {

        ArrayList<String> retList = new ArrayList<>();
        retList = this.getList();

        return retList;
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to try adding the .html appended to the value attribute in your @RequestMapping annotation. So, we would have value = "/ajaxdays.html"

Comment: How try with `url : "<c:url value='ajaxdays.html' />";`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have following errors

1. wrong url

change `url : 'ajaxdays.html'`to `${pageContext.request.contextPath}/ajaxdays`

1. no parameter passed

you are not passing any data to server side so there is no need to write `data: monthSelected`

Comment: I've updated my answer but unfortunately the controller method is not being hit by the AJAX call. I put in some print statements just to see if the method is actually receiving a call.

Answer (score 2):

URL mentioned in ajax call should be the context path followed by the controller mapping. And '.html' should not be specified.

```
 url: ${pageContext.request.contextPath}/ajaxdays
```